# Displace objects to surface

Tags: modeling

My Skill level: Beginner
I am sure this issue is due to my skill level and it is easily achievable.
I was able to do this in Parametric modeling software like Solidworks.

I was wondering if it was possible to do the following in an easier fashion:

Think of the formation like "[Coastal Columnar Basalt](https://media.fromthegrapevine.com/assets/images/2014/9/Giants-Causeway.jpg.824x0_q85.jpg)".

[image: Coastal Columnar Basalt]

I had a large amount of patterned objects I wanted to displace to a curved surface.

What I tried:

1. Shrinkwrap
2. Particles on surface (Hair): The issue here is since the surface is curved, the vertices and faces in orthogonal view are not evenly spaced. This causes a lot of gaps between the objects.

What I am doing currently:
I have the tiled objects and the surface in the scene and I am manually moving each object up till it touches the surface.
I have close to 80000 objects :(

Comment: Could you show us the curved surface where you want to cast objects? And objects itself? Or are you opened for method that will create them from scratch?

Comment: You can easily do this using dupliverts

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47507/animating-multiple-columns-to-sound

Comment: @LukeD I am open to method from scratch. A simple example for the above Basalt columns would suffice.

Thanks

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Could you please upload a blend. Looking at examples will help me better.
I am looking at 47507. I will see how this goes and report back.
I was hoping to not need any addons etc.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I have a setup similar to this
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3418" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3418/)

Comment: Dupliverts need no addons to work, all native Blendfer functionality. The addon suggested at those links was only for the music animation part. Since you don't need that, it should be trivial to do without any dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way is to use a displace modifier with a heightmap. Then use 'UV mapping.' If you use a field of shapes, and set the UV for the top of each cylinder to zero size, then it will be flat on top.

Example blend:
[image]

Comment: This is the best method for such scenes. Thanks.

The height map allows a good overall degree of control on the displacement.