# Question on tapering a bezier curve

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model this medieval wall sconce, in particular this vertical strap component:

[image]

So far I have a 3D Bezier curve with depth and extrude applied:

[image]

I have added a second Bezier curve with which I intend to taper the strap:

[image]

I select the main strap object and assign the taper object to be the second curve:

[image]

I cannot seem to adjust the taper curve in such a way as to achieve the desired effect.

Is this a good approach for this situation and if so, what can I do to get a proper taper on the strap? Are there other, "better" methods for this effect?

Comment: I think using a lattice here would be a good fit - check [this link](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38476/21718) out and see if it looks about right for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would convert the curve to a mesh object with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>> *Mesh from curve/meta/ surf/ text*.

Next,  <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *edit mode* and enable [proportional editing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html#proportional-edit) with <kbd>O</kbd>.

Finally, select just the top few edge loops of the new object and scale while adjusting the proportional edit radius of influence with your mouse wheel until satisfied with the result.

[image]

Comment: How are you changing the size of that white circle?

Comment: @AdamPlocher see my edit. Use the mouse wheel.

Answer (score 1):

A curve is too uniform to really appreciate the shape.

I'd model it as a straight mesh using a Mirror Modifier, then apply it. After that, a Curve Deform Modifier can be used to bend the steel into shape without any distortions.

The rest is just duplicating and rotating around the cursor from above.

[image]