# Shrinkwrap addon conflicting with curve bevel

Tags: animation, add-on, bezier-curves, baking

I have made a grid curve which I beveled for a final result which looks like this:

[image]

I am making an animation out of this, which will make the grid object wave like a flag. To do so, I have shrinkwrapped the grid object to a moving wavy plane, so that the result looks like this:

[image]

Now, the problem is that not only did the curve get shrinkwrapped onto the plane, but also the bevel. Which makes the whole thing flat, as can be seen in the GIF. How can I fix this?

One solution I can think of would be to "bake" the waving animation onto the curve so that I don't need the shrinkwrap addon anymore, thus letting me bevel the curve independently. Unfortunately, I do not know how I can do this.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Shrinkwrap will flatten your object, It might not be the best way to do what you are after. You can try using a lattice and then deforming the lattice using shrinkwrap. Please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26023/in-blender-3d-is-there-any-function-like-flow-along-surface-in-rhino-3d/26048#26048 or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48823/deform-object-after-another-object/48841#48841

Comment: also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38473/creating-a-wave-like-animation-with-plane-image/38475#38475

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be over complicating

*Shrinkwrap* modifier is used to project one **flat** surface over the another, not really very fit for complex animation, nor projecting non-sheet-like objects with volume.

Also curve objects are not really very fit for deformations (a least not in the Z axis), they will inevitably lead to artifacts due to their triangulated nature, lack of proper subdivisions, and non quad based topology.

You should use a base mesh object instead, which also widens the choice of modifiers available, and possibly use a *Wave* modifier instead, unless you need a very specific or precise wave shape.

Only then on top of the *Wave* deformation modifier (or whichever other you choose) apply a *Solidify* to add thickness and a *Bevel* to chamfer or fillet the corners.

That way you will guarantee that the thickness and bevels are not distorted as much by the Wave, nor squashed by the *Shrinkwrap*.

You may optionally add a *Subdivision* modifier set to *Simple* on top of the stack, so you get a smoother mesh with less bevel distortions

[image: Wave grid]

Comment: I've looked into the wave modifier, and it doesn't seem to be able to make perfectly round waves the way I need them to be. I have since found different solutions that might work, though. Thanks for the help anyway!