# How do I make an animated mesh independent of a shrinkwrap modifier?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

The title is probably very confusing, but here's the situation:

I'm animating a flat grid curve by shrink-wrapping it onto a moving plane in order to get a uniform wave animation, it looks like this:

[image]

Before I render it, i want a bevel. What I did then was simply adding a bevel to the curve, making the curve look like this:

[image]

Now, when activating the shrinkwrap modifier, I expexted that only the curve would be shrinkwrapped, but alas, the bevel did the same:

[image]

As seen by the blue spots, the curve has been completely flattened along with the bevel.

How can I avoid this? I tried using a wave modifier instead of shrinkwrap, but this modifier doesn't seem to make perfectly round waves like this:

[image]

So, any thoughs on how to solve this?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You could experiment with Displace modifier, setting its texture coordinates to object and texture to a black-white-black gradient. Then just use any object (can be empty), scale it (it will change wave size) and move around.

Comment: That's gonna do the trick i think. I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: The answer on your question is [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23563/how-to-bake-softbody-animation-into-keyframes). Select your object and use the script, that you find there. It will bake shape changes into animation. And yes, I know it's about softbody, but it will work for you too, just don't forget to turn off the modifier after baking to prevent strange behaviour.

Comment: thanks, altthough I'm a little confused; what does "run the script" mean? Do I select my object and then run the script in the python window?

Comment: Is this the same question? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/shrinkwrap-addon-conflicting-with-curve-bevel If so please edit the original question instead of asking the same thing twice.